# How to get hours and minutes from UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

How do you get the `hours: Int` and `minutes: Int` from a `UIDatePicker`?

I know it has a `.date` property, but I'm finding it difficult to divulge hour and minute values directly. Is there an easier way than doing the 'hacky-ish' way I have in mind, which is to compare the current date to the datePicker's date, then turn that time interval into hours and minutes and add it to the current hours and minutes. Seems overly complex for a seemingly ordinary task...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` just give you the selected `Date`, if you need the date component based on current calendar, check out the `Calendar` and `DateComponent` documendation for details.

```swift
let now = Date() // your date
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: now)

dateComponents.hour
dateComponents.minute
```

If you need `hours` and `minutes` for time distance, you need the calculate it manually with your prefer base date.

Comment: So if the UIDatePicker is 8:30, and I want to store the 8 into the variable `hours: Int` and 30 in the variable `mins: Int`, can I just do `let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: datePicker.date)`, then `hours = dateComponents.hour` and `mins = dateComponents.minute`?

Comment: Random question, why is the argument labeled `from` instead of `for`? That confused me because it seems like it's saying what are the hours and minutes *from* the date until now, or something like that.

Comment: @Eric33187 for `Calendar`, it does the translation **from** `Date` with `Component` set **to** `DateComponents`, smell good!

Comment: Ohhhh gotcha gotcha.